# Detect Refresh action under windows xp

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, desktop, handles

My question is simple. How I can detect if user refreshed explorer under windows xp? Or if it would be easier how to detect if user refreshed desktop?
I heard that I can listen desktop handle. If refresh action will occur I will notice it.

Comment: You can "refresh the desktop", but do you understand what it means? The desktop is just another Explorer window that happens to be fullscreen and quite far down in the Z order.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx
[How can I programmatically refresh Windows Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647316/how-can-i-programmatically-refresh-windows-explorer)

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: Well... he should create a hook and listen to a proper event which refreshes desktop. That's what he wanted, as far as I understood him. Former link shows how to create a hook, later which event should he be listening for.

Comment: The latter shows just one way to force a refresh; it's certainly not the only. F5 in Explorer will NOT broadcast a settings change.

Comment: Well, you're right but you have to admit that it is still a solution. Maybe not the best one, but still a solution

Comment: Thanks yes it is somehow a solution. But I also need a solution for F5. Maybe there is a possibility to disable f5 function? So user will only be able to refresh by rightclick->refresh?